# Restore of MySQL Backup just stuck

Tags: backup, mysql

I have a with mysqldumb created backup file. It's about 15GB and contains a lot of blobs. Max size per blob is 30MB.

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass --compress --quick --skip-opt supertext > supertext.sql
```

Now when I try to restore the backup, the process just gets stuck.

```
mysql -uuser -ppass dev_supertext < supertext.sql
```

It get stuck while writing back the biggest table with the blobs. There is no error message and mysql is still running fine.

This is on a 64bit 5.1.48 community edition for Windows server.

max_allowed_packet is set to 40MB and is not the problem. I had that before.

Any other settings I could check or something I can monitor during the restore? 
Didn't see anything special in the query or error log. Maybe there is a timeout?

Just FYI:
I've already posted this question in the MySQL Forum, but got no response.
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?28,377143

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Keep in mind _writing_ can take a lot longer then dumping (creating indexes, searchable structure, etc.). 15GB doesn't seem that much, but depending on the structure it can very well take hours. What does a `show full processlist;` say?

Comment: I'm aware that it takes long. Normally I start it in the evening and check again in the morning. For more see my comment below. Will do a processlist and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you positive it is only the big table with blobs? Try running the dump sans that table. Do that table individually and if it still gets stuck, break it up.

Create the inserts into 3-4 groups and see if any go through. Process of elimination will help narrow down if theres a row specific issue (I.e. corrupted data?) or if mysql is simply taking a while to write.

I'd advise opening up a second mysql shell or using phpmyadmin to refresh the table view and see if new records are being written. MySQL isn't verbose on its dumps. It may simply be taking a while to load in all the inserts.

Comment: Actually just did split up the dump into 2 tables. One with the blog and one with the rest. The first one goes through fine. The 2nd one is stuck.
I checked with the Query Browser and there are no records written for hours. I will try a split of dump. Does anyone know a good command line splitting tool?